# Shade and Color Hillshade using QGIS

Tags: qgis, hillshade

I am trying to recreate this demo using QGIS only. https://thomasthoren.com/2016/02/28/making-a-new-york-times-map.html

Specifically I am trying to reproduce the hillshade and color portion without using a Makefile and the command terminal (i haven't progressed that far in my technical skills).

`rm -rf tmp && mkdir -p tmp
gdaldem \
    hillshade \
    tif/afghanistan-cropped.tif \
    tmp/hillshade.tmp.tif \
    -z 5 \
    -az 315 \
    -alt 60 \
    -compute_edges
gdal_calc.py \
    -A tmp/hillshade.tmp.tif \
    --outfile=tif/afghanistan-color-crop.tif \
    --calc="255*(A>220) + A*(A<=220)"
gdal_calc.py \
    -A tmp/hillshade.tmp.tif \
    --outfile=tmp/opacity_crop.tmp.tif \
    --calc="1*(A>220) + (256-A)*(A<=220)"`

The result will produce something like this:
[image]

Is it possible to complete this only in QGIS? I have the Raster GDAL plugin installed. I have tried using Raster>Analysis>DEM tool to recreate this but I haven't been able to succeed in getting a similar result.

Comment: Use processing toolbox. `GDAL / Analysis / Hillshade` and `GDAL / Miscellaneous / Raster calculator`

Comment: Could you possible walk me through how to use the Raster calculator. I am not sure how to input this code section using the Raster calculator.      'gdal_calc.py \
    -A tmp/hillshade.tmp.tif \
    --outfile=tif/afghanistan-color-crop.tif \
    --calc="255*(A>220) + A*(A<=220)"
gdal_calc.py \
    -A tmp/hillshade.tmp.tif \
    --outfile=tmp/opacity_crop.tmp.tif \
    --calc="1*(A>220) + (256-A)*(A<=220)" '

Comment: Paste the code in Cmd (Windows) or Terminal (OS X) and run it. Before, go to GDAL folder using `cd` + `path\to\gdal`, you can omit this step if you are a OS X user. Sometimes GDAL functions in QGIS doesn't work as well at the command line. If this is to difficult, use `Raster / Raster calculator`, you can do the same operations and is the easiest way.

Comment: When I use the command line, my result is not as pretty as the image above. The coloring of the map is much darker.

Comment: [Stretch your data](https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/training_manual/rasters/changing_symbology.html), maybe has correct values but visualization isn't the same. Is a common issue, play with raster properties to change colors.

Comment: Thanks! I figured out the problem and got the results I was looking for.

Comment: @mhshaaban could you please explain in your question, or as an answer to your question, what you did to obtain the required result? It might help other people. Cheers,

Comment: @victor I actually ended up using the hillshade.tmp.tif which was exactly what I wanted. I tried stretching my data and could eventually produce other results that would be useful for another project.